# How to accurately extract math expressions without adjacent alphabetic characters

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract the math expressions from the string (assume there are only 4 symbols `+,-,*,/`). It should not contain or attach to any alphabet character. For examples:

```
text = 'a 1*1+1 a`
>>> '1*1+1'

text = `a2*2*2 a`
>>> None

text = `a 3*3+3a`
>>> None

text = `a4*4+4a`
>>> None
```

My regex is a number followed by a group of math symbol `+,-,\,*` with another number (as many repetitions as possible):
`\d+(?:[\*\+/\-]\d+)+`

But this regex will match: `1*1+1` in `a1*1+1a`

If I add `\b` to both sides `\b\d+(?:[\*\+/\-]\d+)+\b` then it will match `2+3` in `a1*2+3` (since `*` is a `\W` character) but it is expected to return None

Should I use lookahead and lookbehind or just split the text before using regex? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Anchors - `^\d+(?:[\*\+/\-]\d+)+$` or whitespace boundaries - `(?<!\S)\d+(?:[\*\+/\-]\d+)+(?!\S)` must help.

Comment: Try `(?<![a-z*+/-])\d+(?:[*+/-]\d+)+(?![a-z*+/-])` https://regex101.com/r/P9F6Tm/1

Comment: What if the string were `'a 2*(1*1+1) a'`? This may match a regex that *excludes* certain characters before and after the sting of interest (here I assume that is `'1*1+1'`),but not match a regex that requires the string of interest to be preceded by a whitespace (or be at the start of the string,) and be followed by a whitespace (or be at the end of the string). I would think the latter requirement would better suit your needs but it's not my question. You may wish to clarify that.

Comment: @CarySwoveland For simplicity, it is assumed that the text only contains expressions with 4 basic operators. I think extending the problem with more symbols is not a hard task. For your case `a 2*(1*1+1) a`, I would like it to returns `2*(1*1+1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your example data, instead of using word boundaries, you can make use of lookarounds excluding one of the four symbols `+`,`-`,`*`,`/` and an alphabet character.

For a case-insensitive match use `re.search(pattern, s, re.IGNORECASE)`

```
(?<![a-z*+/-])\d+(?:[*+/-]\d+)+(?![a-z*+/-])
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VOppC1/1)

Example

```
import re

strings = [
    "a 1*1+1 a",
    "a2*2*2 a",
    "a 3*3+3a",
    "a4*4+4a"
]

pattern = r"(?<![a-z*+/-])\d+(?:[*+/-]\d+)+(?![a-z*+/-])"

for s in strings:
    print(re.search(pattern, s))
```

Output

```
<re.Match object; span=(2, 7), match='1*1+1'>
None
None
None
```